# how to generate a dataset of correlated variables with different distributions?

Tags: matlab, dataset, stata, correlated

For teaching purposes, I need to generate random datasets of correlated random variables with different distributions. I have tried `corr2data` in Stata but it will not allow me to specify max and min values of the variables to be generated, just means, sd's and the covariance matrix. Therefore, I need to do messy adjustments after generation of the data. Various other details annoy me with `corr2data`. Is there a simpler way of doing this with MATLAB? I am not as familiar with this software as I am with Stata.

Comment: Did you take a look at the multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by "different distributions"? All normal, but just different parameters? Or really different: normal and chi-squared and uniform etc. The latter might be pretty hard, because there's no standard way to parametrize correlation between them in the first way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Statistics Toolbox as well as MATLAB, you can use the copula functionality to do this fairly easily. Using a copula, you can specify the marginal distributions of each variable, and a correlation structure between the variables.

You can then generate random numbers from the copula, fit it to data etc. as well.

See in the MATLAB documentation:

[Copulas: Generate Correlated Samples](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/probability-distributions-used-for-multivariate-modeling.html#bqttfgl-1)