# Generate correlated variables in Stata

Tags: variables, random, stata, correlation

I want to generate 5 correlated variables in Stata. Four normally distributed with specific means and standard deviations and one following a bernoulli with probability 0.60.

I tried to follow the advice given in the post:
[How to generate correlated Uniform[0,1] variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718752/how-to-generate-correlated-uniform0-1-variables)

My code is the following:

```
matrix C =     (1,                  ///                                                                 /// 
2*sin(0.05*_pi/6), 1,      /// 
2*sin(-0.45*_pi/6), 2*sin(0.44*_pi/6), 1,            /// 
2*sin(0.22*_pi/6), 2*sin(0.33*_pi/6), 2*sin(-0.54*_pi/6), 1,   /// 
2*sin(0.45*_pi/6), 2*sin(0.32*_pi/6), 2*sin(-0.22*_pi/6), 2*sin(-0.13*_pi/6), 1)    

matrix B = (40, 26, 13, 146, 0.35) 
matrix A = (9, 11, 5, 2, 1)

corr2data var1 var2 var3 var4 var5, n(10000) corr(C) means(B) sds(A) cstorage(lower)

replace var1 = rnormal(var1)
replace var2 = rnormal(var2)
replace var3 = rnormal(var3)
replace var4 = rnormal(var4)

replace var5 = normal(var5)
replace var5 = rbinomial(1,var5)
```

I have gotten what i wanted more or less in the sense that the values that the generated variables have are as expected.

However, is my approach correct? If not, how would you amend the code to properly give the desired results while being scientifically sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. First, the transformation of the correlation matrix is only useful for the special case of generating *uniform* variables, but you want correlated normals and a binomial. Second, you don't need to re-generate var1-var4 with `rnormal`, as `corr2data` already does that for you. Third, your correlation matrix is not positive (semi)definite, so the code does not run as written for me. Fourth, you need to apply the inverse CDF of the Bernoulli distribution to simulate draws from that distribution (that's step 3 in the linked post), and not use `rbinomial()`.

Here's a simplified example with two normals and a Bernoulli:

```
clear
local p=0.6
matrix m = (10,0,0) 
matrix sd = (5,1,1)

/* I am shooting for corr(n1,b)=0.5 and corr(n2,b)=0.75, so I exaggerate their correlations in the bottom row */
matrix c = /// 
(1, /// 
0.5, 1, ///
0.64, 0.95,1)    

corr2data n1 n2 b, n(10000) corr(c) means(m) sds(sd) cstorage(lower)

/* Steps 2-3 for the one Bernoulli variable */
replace b = cond(normal(b)>=(1-`p'),1,0)

/* Check that we did things correctly */
corr, means
qnorm n1
qnorm n2
prtest b = `p'
```

In general, you will have to play around with the correlations between the normals and the Bernoulli variable to get things to come out as you want. It might be possible to automate this search (or come up with an analytical approximation), but I don't have time to code it up or solve it.

Comment: @Cynthia Your suggestion introduces another tuning parameter that needs fiddling, messes up the correlations, and has no theoretical foundations as far as I can tell. Despite the similarity in name, `rnormal()` and `normal()` are very different beasts. If you want to just generate Bernoulli variables (and ignore the correlations), try `gen b = uniform()<=0.6` or `gen b = rbinomial(1,0.6)`.

Comment: @Cynthia Is the goal to create a binary outcome and estimate the coefficients on var1-var5?