# Random draws in Matlab of dependent/independent but not uniform random variables in [0,1]

Tags: matlab, random

Consider the random vector `W=(X,Y)` where `X`and `Y` are scalar random variables with support `[0,1]` and PDF `f`.

I would like to draw `P` realisations of `W` in Matlab, firstly assuming that `x`and `Y`are independent, and then assuming that they are dependent.

I know how to do this in Matlab if I impose `f`being the uniform distribution. Is there any way to do this using other types of `f`?

For example, I am thinking about the beta distribution; I considered the package `betarnd`in Matlab but I couldn't understand how to control the correlation between the random variables.

---

One possibility I thought about

```
clear
P=500; %number draws

% parameters beta 1
mu1=0.896;
v1=0.001;
a1=((1-mu1)/v1 -1/mu1)*mu1^2;
b1=a1*(1/mu1-1);
% parameters beta 1
mu2=0.206;
v2=0.004;
a2=((1-mu2)/v2 -1/mu2)*mu2^2;
b2=a2*(1/mu2-1);

% correlation
rho=0.5;

%Draw bivariate standard normal with correlation rho
mu=[0 0];
sigma=[1 rho; rho 1]; 
R = mvnrnd(mu, sigma, P,1);

%Apply standard normal cdf to each column of R
R2=[normcdf(R(:,1)) normcdf(R(:,2))]; %nxK

%Apply inverse beta cdf to each column of R2
R3=[betainv(R2(:,1), a1, b1)  betainv(R2(:,2), a2, b2)];
```

I am not sure it works however.

Comment: Most functions like `betarnd`, `gammarnd` etc will give an output with statistically independent components. Off the top of my head, only `mvnrnd`  (normal) and `mvtrnd` (Student's t) allow defining an input covariance matrix

Comment: @LuisMendo I thought about this now: do you think it may work?

Comment: I don't think so. The degree of correlation is not preserved under non-linear transformations. You may be lucky, though. I had to do that once and found that, for my specific transformation, the correlation before and after was approximately the same. You would need to do the numerical computations to be sure

Comment: Related question (possibly both answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718752/how-to-generate-correlated-uniform0-1-variables

Comment: It may be appropriate to ask this question at https://math.stackexchange.com or https://stats.stackexchange.com instead